# The terminal says that the view was rendered but it doesn't actually renders in the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

The following controller does the following:

If the current user's ID exists in the user_id attribute of one of the vote instances, the current user will be redirected to this page with a notice telling him that he or he already voted. If not, the vote will be cast and render `views/votes/vote_up.js.erb`.

**votes_controller.erb:**

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def vote_up
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.votes.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id)
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'You already voted'
    else
      @vote = @post.votes.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :polarity => 1)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**views/posts/show.html.erb:**

```
<div class="post-<%=@post.id%>">
  <h3><span class="vote-count"><%= @post.votes.count %></span>votes</h3><br />
  <%= link_to "Vote Up", vote_up_path(@post), :remote => true, :class => "vote-up" %><br />
</div>
```

Everything works Ok except that the user is not being redirected and the notice is not appearing. I just get this notice in the terminal:

> CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2
>   ORDER BY users.created_at ASC LIMIT 1 Rendered posts/show.html.erb
>   within layouts/application (386.5ms) Completed 200 OK in 428ms (Views:
>   416.5ms | ActiveRecord: 7.3ms)

Any suggestions to fix this? (by the way, is it more redable to use unless `here` (how)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect doesn't work because you are calling the `vote_up` method via Ajax. You should display the notice with javascript, just like you are doing when the user hasn't voted yet.

You could do something like this:

```
def vote_up
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  if @post.votes.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id)
    @notice = 'You already voted'
  else
    @vote = @post.votes.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :polarity => 1)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then in your `.erb.js` file, you send back javascript depending on whether `@notice` and `@vote` are blank or not.

```
<% unless @notice.blank? %>
  // javascript to display @notice
<% end %>

<% unless @vote.blank? %>
  // javascript to increase vote count
<% end %>
```

Comment: You mean creating another `js.erb` file? Sorry, I'm a Rails beginner. How would it look like in the controller?

Comment: Maybe you can use the same `.js.erb` file.

Comment: Could you give me a hint of how to do that?